# Add nodes to almost all branches in a tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to create a tree structure of all possible combinations of value pairs from two lists

I have two linked lists `L1 = {A, B, C}` and `L2 = {1, 2, 3}`. I want to create a tree structure that lets me pull out all unique combinations of these two lists:

```
root--A1--B2--C3
 | |   |
 | |   --B3--C2
 | |
 | A2--B1--C3
 |  |
 |   --B3--C1
 |
 --A3--B1--C2
    |
    --B2--C1
```

Only 1 instance of any member of each list can be in any complete branch of the tree. I want this to work with any size of both L1, L2

Requirements for the tree:

- Each node contains an array of pointers to each element pair
- Each branch can only contain one instance of each element of the two lists
- Each branch has to be as long as possible

  - The length of a branch should be the size of L1, and the amount of nodes connected to the root node should be the same as the length of L2.

My tree consists of 2 structs:

```
typedef struct _TR tree;
typedef struct _TN tree_node;

struct _TR
{
    unsigned int tree_depth;
    tree_node * root;
};


struct _TN
{
    List_item * items[2];
    unsigned int node_count;
    tree_node  * parent_node;
    tree_node ** child_nodes;
};
```

The tree is built by the following function

```
void addToAllBranches(List_item * item_array[2], tree_node * curr_node)
{
    if (curr_node->node_count == 0) // Problem, some how
    {

        if (!checkIfExistsInBranch(curr_node->parent_node, item_array)) // Checks if any member of the pair exists in the current branch (straight following each parent node)
            addNode(curr_node, createNode(item_array)); //If it doesn't exist, add it. Otherwise do nothing
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < curr_node->node_count)
    {
        addToAllBranches(item_array, curr_node->child_nodes[i]);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Which is called by

```
/* Walks through each possible pair and tries to add them to the tree*/
void addPairsToTree(List * L1, List * L2, tree * root_tree)
{
    List_item * L1_list_wlkr = L1->top_item;
    List_item * L2_list_wlkr;
    List_item * item_array[2];

    while (L1_list_wlkr != NULL)
    {
        L2_list_wlkr = L2->top_item;
        while (L2_list_wlkr != NULL)
        {
            item_array[0] = L1_list_wlkr;
            item_array[1] = L2_list_wlkr;
            addToAllBranches(item_array, root_tree->root);

            L2_list_wlkr = L2_list_wlkr->next_item;
        }

        L1_list_wlkr = L1_list_wlkr->next_item;
    }

}
```

With the checking function:

```
int checkIfExistsInBranch(tree_node * curr_node, List_item * check[2])
{
    tree_node * tree_wlkr = curr_node;
    while(tree_wlkr != NULL)
    {
        if(tree_wlkr->items[0] == check[0] || tree_wlkr->items[1] == check[1])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        tree_wlkr = tree_wlkr->parent_node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the tree structure I get it seems to look like something like this:

```
root--A1--A2--B2--B3--C3
```

Which doesn't make sense, I feel like the output should be something along the lines of:

```
root--A1--B2--C3
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is caused by the line:

```
if (curr_node->node_count == 0) // Problem, some how
```

Which causes the adding function only to add onto empty branches.
I am unsure on what to change it to which still makes the tree fulfill the size requirements.

My questions are:

1. What do I change the `if (curr_node->node_count == 0) // Problem, some how` line to?
2. How come the `checkIfExistsInBranch` fails with the current way the algorithm is implemented?

Comment: Post `c_list_wlkr` declaration as used in `while (c_list_wlkr != NULL)`.  I see no initialization for it.  No next, no increment.  Maybe it should be `L1_list_wlkr`.

Comment: @chux Thank you. Missed that when I rewrote the function for SO